# Perl regular expression to retrieve the first digit

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string with the value `Validation_File_2_3.45.2017.csv`.

How do I extract the first digit which is 2 in this case using a regular expression?

I have tried the expression `($Filedigit) = ($Filename =~ m/^[0-9]/g)` but it didn't work

Comment: What have you tried? What are the escape characters for digits and non-digits? How do you capture a value in a regex?

Comment: Hi I have tried the expression ($Filedigit)= ($Filename =~ m/^[0-9]/g);

Comment: @GauraviNaik: Okay, and what happened when you tried that? Why are you making us work so hard to get the information we need to answer you? You should also *edit* your question to add information, not write it in comments. I have done it for you this time, but we still need to know what problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, you said you tried this:

```
($Filedigit)= ($Filename =~ m/^[0-9]/g);
```

A couple of things. You should *always* check that a match is successful before continuing on with your script, specifically when trying to capture. Next, `^` looks from the beginning of a string, then immediately looks for a single digit `0-9`, globally. This won't match unless you had a filename such as `2_blah.csv`. However, you're not actually attempting to capture anything, so if you do happen to match an entry, `$Filedigit` will be `1` in all cases (signifying a match happened).

Here's an example that does what you want:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $str = 'Validation_File_2_3.45.2017.csv';

# confirm there's a match

if (my ($num) = $str =~ /^.*?(\d+)/){
    print "$num\n";
}
else {
    print "no match\n";
}
```

Explanation of the regex:

```
^   - start from beginning of string
.*? - anything, non-greedy
(   - begin capture
\d+ - any number of contiguous digit chars
)   - end capture
```

So, it starts from the beginning of the string, throws away anything before the first set of contiguous digits and captures them and puts that into the variable.

See [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).